# Is it possible to use teamcity message from shell scripts?

Tags: shell, teamcity, build-process

I have several build steps that use command line with custom scripts. And i want to use teamcity messages. Like this ones:

```
##teamcity[message 'value']
##teamcity[buildNumber '<new build number>']
##teamcity[buildStatus status='<status value>' text='<text>']
```

But it seems that this commands are  not working at all. What's wrong with them? Is it possible to run this commands in shell scripts in teamcity? Any ideas how to use them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a shell script, use

```sh
echo "##teamcity[buildStatus status='<status value>' text='<text>']"
```

Here is the [detailed docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html) for TeamCity 2020.2.

Comment: It should. If not, you may want to file a bug to TeamCity team (I've added the documentation link)

Comment: you can use this gist https://gist.github.com/VladRassokhin/e24509b7a85386e6374b7580c840dc71